# Function getting called 2 times in OnLongClickListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I have this code in my `adapter` for `RecyclerView`:

```
holder.image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    int[] loc = new int[2];
    holder.image.getLocationInWindow(loc);
    ((FeedFragment) fragment).blurBackground(getBitmapFromView(holder.image), loc[0], loc[1]);
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Long press started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    isLongPressed = true;
    return true;
  }
});

holder.image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.onTouchEvent(event);
    // We're only interested in when the button is released.
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      // We're only interested in anything if our speak button is currently pressed.
      if (isLongPressed) {
        // ((FeedFragment) fragment).removeBlur();
        ((FeedFragment) fragment).showAllGalleries(String.valueOf(photo.getPk()));
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Long press ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Do something when the button is released.
        isLongPressed = false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

So what I want to do is: as soon as the long click starts, I want to call a method to blur the screen except the image where long click happens and this blurring(changing alpha of background) happens in 400 ms.

The issue is, the `blurBackground()` method is being called twice. So when I remove the blurring in `onActivityResult`, I only remove the last added layer, whereas another layer of blur is present because of the method getting called twice. I expect the `blurBackground()` method to be called only once.

What is the cause of this behaviour and how can it be fixed?

Here are other methods:

```
public void blurBackground(Bitmap bitmapFromView, int left, int top) {
  LogUtil.i(TAG, "blurBackground called");

  int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

  RelativeLayout overlay = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
  ID_OVERLAY = ViewIDGenerator.generateViewId();
  LogUtil.i(TAG, "ID = " + ID_OVERLAY);
  overlay.setId(ID_OVERLAY);
  overlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams overlayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  overlay.setLayoutParams(overlayParams);

  ImageView snapshot = new ImageView(getActivity());
  snapshot.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromView);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams snapshotParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  snapshotParams.setMargins(left, top-statusBarHeight, 0, 0);
  snapshot.setLayoutParams(snapshotParams);

  overlay.addView(snapshot);
  container.addView(overlay);

  AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 0.7f);
  alphaAnimation.setDuration(400);
  alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
  overlay.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
}

public void removeBlur() {
  LogUtil.i(TAG, "removeBlur called");
  LogUtil.i(TAG, "ID = " + ID_OVERLAY);
  View namebar = container.findViewById(ID_OVERLAY);
  ((ViewGroup) namebar.getParent()).removeView(namebar);
}
```

Comment: Are you registering your listeners in the getView() method in your adapter ? Since you're using RecyclerView , the algorithm might be calling it twice.

Comment: @Lazai but it would not be called everytime `getView()` is called. it will be called only when you touch that view.

Answer (score 1):

if your only problem is that blurBackground is beign called twice, you can just raise a flag!

```
Boolean isBlurred = false;
```

then in blurBackground

```
public void blurBackground(Bitmap bitmapFromView, int left, int top) {
  if (!isBlurred)
  { 
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "blurBackground called");

    ...
    isBlurred = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: ya, this is one way, but I am more interested in why is it so.

Answer (score 0):

return true for the onTouch method, this way you are telling that you handled the event.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    doSomething();
    return true;
}
```